# On-boarding email asks for soft copy and not scanned copy - isn't that contradictory?

Tags: communication, new-job, hiring-process, email

As part of the on-boarding process at the new company that I'm about to join, the email asked for soft copies of certain documents/photographs. One line of instruction that got me confused was this with regard to passport size photograph:

> A soft copy of passport sized photograph. Make sure it isn't a scanned image of hard copy photograph.

I'm kinda stumped right now. When you scan a document/photograph, doesn't it make it a soft copy? And if not, then how would I create a soft copy of my photograph?

Comment: No, it's not a copy-paste. I typed that in manually. It's also not "or".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It means take an original, digital photograph and submit that. i.e. Don't take a photo, print it then scan it. Don't take a picture of a picture either.

Comment: I can see how this would "fit" what they're saying, but I never would have come up with that reading the verbiage provided.

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious - but doesn't a "digital" photo mean taking a pic with a camera? How else would it be converted to a soft copy?

Comment: For all intents and purposes yes, it does; almost every camera these days does nothing but take digital pics, so the extra word is redundant. However, there are plenty of enthusiasts who have analogue cameras, which use actual "film" that is developed - see google. The point I was really trying to convey was not to use a pre-taken photo, eg from a booth, and then scan or photograph that.